# how to sort an array of objects on a calculated field with graphql

Tags: sorting, graphql

Right now i'm trying to solve the problem where a calculated field for each object in a set of objects is dependent on input from the client and the results need to be sorted by this calculated field.

I know it is easily solvable using SQL, but let's say the query results  are dependent on multiple external API's and calculated fields are dependent on the results of these API requests. How would the client be able to sort these query results using one of the available calculated fields?

Comment: if you get result on frontend then use lodash and if you want the direact result then change resolver with sort option.

Comment: Are you asking how should a client handle sorting the result after it's received? Or are you asking how to implement the API to allow a sort argument that would include a calculated field?

Comment: How to implement the API to allow a sort argument that would include a calculated field.